# AWS Elasticsearch Service - Manual Snapshot to S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

i try to create a manual snapshot of my "Amazon Elasticsearch Service"
I found this [documentation](https://sysadmins.co.za/aws-elasticsearch-register-s3-repository-for-snapshots-using-the-cli/) but i have problems with the last step, Registering Snapshot Repository. I search a solution for .net but this example is a python script i can not found a solution for .net

Is a solution available to sign requests for c#?

**phyton script to sign requests**

```
from boto.connection import AWSAuthConnection

class ESConnection(AWSAuthConnection):

    def __init__(self, region, **kwargs):
        super(ESConnection, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._set_auth_region_name(region)
        self._set_auth_service_name("es")

    def _required_auth_capability(self):
        return ['hmac-v4']

if __name__ == "__main__":

    client = ESConnection(
            region='eu-west-1',
            host='search-domain.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com',
            profile_name='ifOtherThanDefault',
            is_secure=False)

    print 'Registering Snapshot Repository'
    resp = client.make_request(method='PUT',
            path='/_snapshot/es-index-backups',
            data='{"type": "s3","settings": { "bucket": "my-es-snapshot-repo","region": "eu-west-1","role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/es-snapshots-role"}}')
    body = resp.read()
    print body
```

**C# Solution**

```
var createRoleJson = @"{
  ""Version"": ""2012-10-17"",
  ""Statement"": [
    {
      ""Sid"": """",
      ""Effect"": ""Allow"",
      ""Principal"": {
        ""Service"": ""es.amazonaws.com""
      },
      ""Action"": ""sts:AssumeRole""
    }
  ]
}
";

var createPolicyJson = @"{
    ""Version"":""2012-10-17"",
    ""Statement"":[
        {
            ""Action"":[
                ""s3:ListBucket""
            ],
            ""Effect"":""Allow"",
            ""Resource"":[
                ""arn:aws:s3:::my-es-snapshot-repo""
            ]
        },
        {
            ""Action"":[
                ""s3:GetObject"",
                ""s3:PutObject"",
                ""s3:DeleteObject"",
                ""iam:PassRole""
            ],
            ""Effect"":""Allow"",
            ""Resource"":[
                ""arn:aws:s3:::my-es-snapshot-repo/*""
            ]
        }
    ]
}";
```

Amazon Requests (AWSSDK.IdentityManagement)

```
//Change the bucket to the correct bucket
var s3BucketName = "test.elasticsearch";
createPolicyJson = createPolicyJson.Replace("my-es-snapshot-repo", s3BucketName);


var awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey");
var client = new AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(awsCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);

var createRoleRequest = new CreateRoleRequest
{
    RoleName = "ElasticsearchSnapshotsRole",
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument = createRoleJson
};

var createPolicyRequest = new CreatePolicyRequest
{
    PolicyName = "ElasticsearchSnapshotAccess",
    PolicyDocument = createPolicyJson
};

var responseCreateRole = client.CreateRole(createRoleRequest);
var responseCreatePolicy = client.CreatePolicy(createPolicyRequest);
var responseAttachRolePolicy = client.AttachRolePolicy(new AttachRolePolicyRequest { PolicyArn = responseCreatePolicy.Policy.Arn, RoleName = responseCreateRole.Role.RoleName });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find reference code on creating signed HTTP requests here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateSignatureInCSharp.html

Complete details of manual snapshot process for AWS elasticsearch can be found at : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html